# Applescript -10810 Error

Tags: php, applescript

I have to run an applescript that convert images with "image events" and I have to run the script with PHP.

If I run the script with command line in terminal or from AppleScript editor, all works correctly, but if I try to run the script with shell_exec or exec PHP command -10810 error happens.

This is the code.
The Error happens at the "open" command of "Image Events" but also happens at first command of every application.

```
on run {myFoto, myThumb}
try
set myTmpWidth to 1772
set myFoto to "Macintosh HD:Library:WebServer:Documents:imgProdotti:alta:" & myFoto     
    set myThumb to "Macintosh HD:Library:WebServer:Documents:imgProdotti:alta:" & myThumb
    set myWidth to myTmpWidth * 1

    tell application "Image Events"

        set myImage to open myFoto
        tell myImage
            scale to size myTmpWidth
            save as JPEG in myThumb
            close
        end tel 
    end tell

on error error_message
    return error_message
end try 
end run
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: You have to show some code. I couldn't find the error number so without seeing any code I can't know what the problem is.

Comment: on run {myFoto, myThumb}
 try  set myTmpWidth to 1772 -- (15 CM a 300 dpi)
  set myFoto to "Macintosh HD:Library:WebServer:Documents:imgProdotti:alta:" & myFoto  
  set myThumb to "Macintosh HD:Library:WebServer:Documents:imgProdotti:alta:" & myThumb
  set myWidth to myTmpWidth * 1
  
  tell application "Image Events"
     
   set myImage to open myFoto
   tell myImage
    scale to size myTmpWidth
    save as JPEG in myThumb
    close
   end tel 
  end tell
  
 on error error_message
  return error_message
 end try 
end runw

Comment: Are you using the `osascript` command to run the AppleScript from `exec()` or `shell_exec()?

Answer (score 0):

```
set myImage to open myFoto
                       ^
                       |
```

You're basically trying to open a string, which you can't do. When you initiliaze `myFoto`, coerce it into an alias reference like so:

```
set myFoto to "Macintosh HD:Library:WebServer:Documents:imgProdotti:alta:" & myFoto as alias
```

Do the same thing for the `myThumb` variable; you will get an error otherwise.

Also (this might just be a typo) there is a compilation error at line 15: `end tel`